# How to cancel browser navigation that is already in progress with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

I don't believe this is possible but thought I'd give it a shot.

As part of a project that I'm working on, there is a page on a different site that a user can navigate to via a standard anchor link. The destination page is sometimes rather slow to respond and the client wants to put a "timeout" in place so that if it is taking too long to navigate to the destination page, to cancel the browser navigation and show a message.

Is it possible with Javascript to cancel a browser navigation that is already in progress (i.e. the request to the destination site has already been made)? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I conducted a simple test, it is possible. I used PHP to conduct the test but this will not be an issue if you use a different language. The bottom line is JavaScript can do it as seen in `cancel.php`. Please see the sample code:

### sleep.php

```
<?php
sleep(30);
echo 'hello';
?>
```

### cancel.php

```
<h1>hello?</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
location.href='sleep.php';
setTimeout(function(){
    location.href='#';
    alert('it is taking too long to respond, probably the site is down!');
}, 10000);
</script>
```

After running cancel.php, it will redirect to sleep.php. After 10 seconds of loading time, it will stop loading sleep.php and conclude that the site is down.

Comment: Interesting. This works in Chrome but not in Firefox (at least on my end). However, as my page has a routed Backbone app on it, I need the hash to stay in place and simply setting it back to itself won't trigger any kind of navigation. I'd love a way to simply cancel the current navigation request.

Answer (score -2):

You can redirect to somewhere else, while the current DOM is still alive.

I ran this simple test, and it redirects to yahoo.com

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    document.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
});​
```

I havent tested with a timer, but seems like it should work, although I cant be sure 100%.
Please post your findings!

Comment: downvote? (frown).. anyone care to explain why? With or without a timer it does test the same thing essentially, that whether the original page still has the control to navigate away before the response from the target page arrives, which is what the OP is asking. 

Please give reasons for downvoting. If my point is silly or invalid, please point out hwat about it is wrong so I can learn too and if required correct/improve my answer with no ego. By simply downvoting no one gains anything.