# Can I manipulate the DOM after the user clicks a link?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of browsers once a link has been clicked, or a form has been submitted - any operation which is triggered by the user, and ends with them landing at a new URL. I've been asked to install some tracking code on buttons and links, which relies on updating an invisible iframe's `src` attribute on click.

So - my specific questions are:

- Can I rely on the DOM being manipulable once the user has clicked a link? That is, can I update attributes on nodes, and is there any assurance that this will succeed before the new page loads?
- Are any requests that are fired by these manipulations (eg, I give an iframe a new `src` attribute) reliable? Obviously, the new page has loaded by the time the request would complete - but it's possible (but probably not trackable) that the request has gone out successfully.

My gut instinct is that neither of these is reliable - and I definitely wouldn't write a system like this myself. I'm really looking for references or spec's so I can make the case for doing this a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, No.

Once the URL changes (and navigation moves entirely away form the page) the present DOM is as good as done. Changes may take place in very rare cases, while waiting for the click action to take affect and the new page to load but this is incredibly unreliable.

The normal way to handle tracking in a web application is to do the tracking server side, as this obviously delegates where the user is being navigated to.

For a purely client side tracking implementation you would need to provide a hook, which catches the click actions, does any tracking and then executes the desired action after the tracking process is finished. One way to do this is a document scoped click event that intercepts all clicks, tracks any info and then delegates the actions as needed. Another way is to define your own click event just for navigation links, unfortunately I can personally only supply a jQuery code snippet for this, not standard JavaScript.

The solution provided by 'karaxuna' is a good demonstration of the document scope mechanism in plain JavaScript.

---

**Update**

For documentation that helps highlight why post navigation processing is unreliable, please refer to the following link:

[W3 navigation timing for web applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/)

Comment: This is the sort of answer I'm looking for. I'm not necessarily looking for a 'how can I?' solution - rather an explanation of how and why this type of manipulation is unreliable. Do you know of any specific documentation or spec for this behaviour?

Comment: Also, please see my comment on karaxuna's answer: I don't want to capture the event to do tracking - particularly when the tracking relies on a 3rd party resource being loaded - if the 3rd party doesn't respond, I'd need timeouts and fallbacks in place - yuck.

Comment: Server-side tracking isn't an option in this case. My preferred solution is add an identifier to the target URL, and do the tracking  on that page: track when the user lands, not as they're leaving.

Comment: @Beejamin Given your situation it seems the best way to do it is by using an event like window.onload (with jQuery its very easy to attach the ready or load events to documents, iframes, images, etc...). Using this you can track not only when the user lands on a page, but also when certain resources are loaded or otherwise ready.

Comment: @Beejamin I don't know of any specific documentation of browser navigation lifecycle off hand, but this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278660/how-to-cancel-browser-navigation-that-is-already-in-progress-with-javascript) might be useful as it looks at 'cancelling' a URL relocation that takes too long.

Comment: Thanks mate - I'm happy with how to implement the solution I have in mind. Unfortunately I'm in the ugly position of looking for ammunition to use against someone else's solution! Thanks for your help - if no-one comes up with browser documentation, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Beejamin I don't personally have time to read it all, but this might give you some ammo [W3 Navigation Timing](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#processing-model)

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I'm after - particularly the timing/sequence of the unload event. If you add the link to your answer, I'll accept it now. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 5):

You can continue page loading after all operations complete. Like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a'){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
        // do your job here
        window.location.href = href; // navigate
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRVsj/)

Comment: Yep - I'm aware I can capture the event, but that means the primary functionality of the site (submitting the form, clicking the link), is reliant on the secondary function (tracking the clicks). It's relevant, and as good a solution as there is, but it's not really what I'm getting at. Thanks - have an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

You must 'intercept' the event before it is allowed to complete. This is easiest done with jquery. You can do something like:

```
$(document).on(
   "click",
   '.button',
   function(e){
       //do fancy stuff like update the iframe here
   });
```